# tmux: Lock session only when using tmux on console, not from a graphical DE

Tags: tmux, screen-lock

When using `tmux` on the tty, I want it to automatically lock after some time. This works with the following configuration in `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g lock-command vlock
set -g lock-after-time 30 # Seconds; 0 = never
```

I got used to `tmux` and also want to use it from a graphical login session (e.g. GNOME on Wayland), I'm using `tmux` there too (e.g. through GNOME terminal). In this case, the graphical login session already has a lockscreen so I don't need `vlock` any more.

How can I automatically make `tmux`:

- lock the screen when run on tty
- not lock the screen when run within a graphical login session

Comment: Thanks for the question! Is it possible to lock the client instead of the server? Then this logic would be easier…

Comment: About the logic: How could this look like? Specifying a script instead of the `vlock` command which (depending on the tmux client) would either `exec vlock` or terminate?

Comment: I think that you have to think the logic behind this a bit more. What about attaching tmux both to a ssh session AND a graphical terminal emulator?

Comment: Good news is `lock-command vlock` runs `vlock` where the tmux client runs, so it can lock each client independently and it can test what the tty is. However in my Kubuntu your original setup led me to a situation where a non-graphical terminal returned to the tmux session after I failed to authenticate in `vlock`. I wonder if there's a bug or I'm missing something. Please confirm that the setup in question really prevents attackers from getting inside tmux in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lock-command vlock` runs `vlock` where the tmux client runs. Any client can be locked independently. In general the argument is a shell command, not necessarily a single executable.

The following tmux command will tell apart `/dev/tty*` from anything else (e.g. `/dev/pts/*`) on the client:

```
set -g lock-command 'tty | grep -q "^/dev/tty" && vlock'
```

**However** in my tests in Kubuntu 18.04.5 LTS `vlock` 2.2.2 allows unauthorized access after authentication failure when run in a non-graphical console. This happens even if I run `vlock` directly from a shell outside of tmux. Your original setup in question also allows unauthorized access in my case. The tool exits in the middle of printing the next prompt. I strongly suspect a bug.

The answer stays because it does solve the problem of running `vlock` conditionally. What happens next seems to be a separate issue. Please check if your `vlock` works as it should and is not a security hole.

Comment: About the security issue you are seeing: Am I understanding you correctly that, if you run `vlock` on a shell, after it immediately exits after you type in the wrong password and then press `[Enter]`?
This is different from what I am seeing. I can type incorrect passwords and never leave `vlock`. The only way vlock terminates for me is after I type in the right password.

Comment: @genodeftest Normally it prompts for `root's password` after I type a wrong user's password. In a case of the bug(?) it prints `root's ` without a newline and exits, so the lock is gone and the prompt of the shell appears. When I try to `strace`, the bug does not occur.

Comment: That's pretty weird. In my case it never asks for root's password after I mistyped my password. Actually it seems to loop forever until I can type in my own password. I'm using `vlock` 2.4.0 from the `kbd` package on Fedora ([Source code](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/kbd/tree/f34) and [upstream](https://kbd-project.org/)).
I was unable to find the upstream for the Ubuntu package but it looks like it has a different codebase as Fedora's `kbd` did not have 2.2.2 released when (K)ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released.

Comment: The fact that it does not happen under `strace` looks like a memory corruption bug which manifests only in specific memory situations. Can you try running it under `valgrind`+`gdb`?

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It works for me on Fedora 34.